# Problem with Czech collation Czech_CI_AI in MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following issue with accent insensitive search in Czech language. My database is set to `Czech_CI_AI` collation. For some diacritics system works correctly (ie. `I`), but for some does not (ie. `R`). In my database there are several `'DVORA*'` records:

```
SELECT contact_name 
FROM   CONTCTSM1 
WHERE  CONTACT_NAME LIKE 'DVO%'
```

Results:

> DVOŘÁČKOVÁ,
>     IVETA DVOŘÁČKOVÁ,
>     JIŘINA DVOŘÁK

Comment: I see the same behaviour with the newer 100 collation too. `SELECT 1 WHERE N'R' = N'Ř' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AI` returns nothing.

Comment: [Looks like you already got an answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/d90d63ad-15f2-4cb5-bc96-8894bf4c7d6d/)

Answer (score 6):

R and Ř are different letters, as opposed to modified base letters(?) like German umlauts with ö vs o

From [Czech language on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_alphabet) (my bold)

> The acute accent (čárka) letters (Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ý) and the kroužek letter Ů all indicate long vowels. They have the **same** alphabetical ordering as their non-diacritic counterparts. ...The háček (ˇ) indicates historical palatalization of the base letter. The letters Č, Ř, Š, and Ž currently represent postalveolar consonants and are ordered **behind** their corresponding base letters; while Ď, Ň, Ť represent palatal consonants and have the same alphabetical ordering as their non-diacritic counterparts.

A test with Ö and O in Swedish (different letters) and German (modified)

```
SELECT 'Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AI' 
          WHERE N'Ö' COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AI = N'O'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Latin1_General_CI_AI' 
          WHERE N'Ö' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = N'O'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's all nice and dandy, but while R and Ř should be treated differently while sorting, they should be considered the same when comparing "accent insensitively". Dvořák should be sorted after Dvorak and even "dobře" after "dobrý", it makes no sense whatsoever no to find "Dvořák" when searching for "Dvorak" ignoring accents.
As it is, the accent insensitive Czech collations are worse than useless.

Answer (score 1):

SQL collation seems not very useful accent insensitive search.

The best solution seems to be to convert the string to varchar with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS.

Either as a persistent column holding varchar value with the 1251 collation or cast the value directly in query (if you don't care that it will go through whole table since there won't be an index).

```
WHERE 
    (cast([name] as varchar(255))) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS 
    like 
    (cast(N'dvoř%' as varchar(255)))  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
```