# Treating certain Arabic characters as identical

Tags: sql-server, collation

In Arabic we have characters like ا (alef) and أ (alef with hamza).

Users write them interchangeably and we want to search them interchangeably.  SQL Server treats them as separate characters. How can I make SQL treat them as the same character?

I thought to replace any أ (alef with hamza) with ا (alef) at insertion but we have a lot of alternatives in Arabic language not just ا (alef) and أ (alef with hamza).

I tried `Arabic_CI_AS` and `Arabic_CI_AI` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Here is a script to regenerate the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] (
    [ArabicChars] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [ArabicChars] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY];


INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'احمد');
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'أحمد');

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE ArabicChars like N'ا%';
```

The result is:

```
ArabicChars 

احمد

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The desired result would be both of the rows we inserted.

Comment: No problem.  Aaron Bertrand has [a nice little script](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3834/2660) that you can adapt to test out all possible collations. However, I suspect no collation will consider those two characters the same.

Comment: but you're having two different chars in the the names stated, atleast in appearance. And of course, I think they should be treated as different chars `ا and أ`

Comment: Have you considered using [SOUNDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) or [DIFFERENCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) to match words that sound similar? I don't know if those functions work for languages other than English, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @NickChammas as you guessed 
SOUNDEX() return 0000 for any Arabic character

Comment: @nuux actually i dont know if they are one character or two (i mean in language grammer)

Comment: Is this the same problem as this? http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12438/630 That is, they are different letters not the same accented letter?

Comment: @gbn - They are different letters.  A [hamza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza) by itself is actually a letter in its own right.

Comment: @NickChammas: which is the problem then: user behaviour+assumption differs from the stricter collation behaviour.

Comment: @George Botros: we can't fix this at the database level I'd say because of the fundamental difference in my last comment...

Comment: @gbn - Given that these are different letters, I'd say the issue is user education.  If users want those letters to be treated equally -- especially in a search -- then that functionality needs to be explicitly built. It is not a collation issue.

Comment: George, I suggest first looking for existing libraries that will help you with the task of mapping Arabic letters to "common denominators" in the application layer. Otherwise, consider building a table that maps a set of `NCHAR(1)` characters to other `NCHAR(1)` characters. You can use that table to reduce input strings to a common format for searching. This will work best only if the fields you're searching on are short, since they too will need to be reduced. If this sounds promising to you, I can write a complete answer explaining this solution.

Comment: This is definitely user education. Even if it doesn't change the pronunciation, it makes a difference as to which character is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i did few tests and i guess it is a work around but can get your job done, since SQL it self isn't helping much.

if you notice that the unicodes of these characters are close to each other

```
select unicode(N'أ')
  = 1571

select unicode(N'ا')
  = 1575

select unicode(N'إ')
  = 1573
```

so between أ and ا , its from 1571 to 1575
or if you want to make sure you get every thing in between

make sure you include from 1569 to 1575

which are

```
Select NCHAR(1569) = ء
Select NCHAR(1570) = آ
Select NCHAR(1571) = أ
Select NCHAR(1572) = ؤ
Select NCHAR(1573) = إ
Select NCHAR(1574) = ئ 
Select NCHAR(1575) = ا
```

So to make sure that you include every thing similar in your search you can use regular expressions

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE ArabicChars like '%[ء-ا]%'
```

so in this case you get all characters between ء and ا
which include all those between 1569 to 1575

so in this case if your table has

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]  (
    [ArabicChars] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NOT NULL,
) 
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'احمد');
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'أحمد');
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'إحمد');
```

the query above will get them all.

but you will notice something funny

if you have your column as a primary key

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]  (
    [ArabicChars] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [ArabicChars] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

you wont be able to insert these 2 records

```
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'أحمد');
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'إحمد');
INSERT INTO TestTable values (N'ءحمد');
```

because the ء,أ,إ
are all to SQL are part of hamza which is ء

So if you run the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE ArabicChars like 'ء%'
```

it will show you

```
أحمد
إحمد
```

so to get the long story short

to SQL أ is not = to ا because its 2 different letters
hamza and alefp

but ء = آ = أ = ؤ = إ = ئ

they are all Hamza  **ء**

Comment: ***Great work*** @AmmarR

Comment: The idea of using regex for this is  No more collation and other stuff headaches

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the most complicated issues i have passed through

so i will write you all what i tried that didnt work, may be you can start after that

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]  (
    [ArabicChars] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [ArabicChars] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

i created your column using COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI 
where CI = case insensitive
and AI = accent insensitive, and this is where its suppose to work because if you chose another language like for example S and Š, it works

i also tried changing the database collation to Arabic_CI_AI 
still didn't work

you can also collate the script like

SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE ArabicChars COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI like 'ا%'
COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI;

and it still didn't work

check out this article it speaks about the same issue but from sorting point

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295829(SQL.90).aspx

this is taken from the article

> For example, a sort order defines whether the Arabic character '' is
>   less than, equal to, or greater than ''. It also defines whether the
>   collation is accent-sensitive (for example, whether '' is equal or is
>   not equal to '').

here is another person who researched this problem but couldnt find any solution
http://www.siao2.com/2008/11/11/9056745.aspx

trying to ignore diacritics or hamza i guess isnt possible in sql server currently

may be future versions

Comment: *Good Work* @AmmarR

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose mentioned in this post, you may only use: **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS**   [ it works for Arabic and Persian as well as English/Latin character sets ].